# Menu link on hover is showing &amp; instead of &

Tags: entities, routes, i18n-l10n, theming, navigation

I have a Webform that provides a menu link. The webform is available in three languages (dutch, french, english).

For the dutch version I have a **menu title** of `Informatie` and **description** `Vragen & Antwoorden`.

But when I hover the link I don't get `Vragen & Antwoorden`. But i get `Vragen &amp; Antwoorden`.

He changes the & symbol to [&](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) . I also got this with `'` . He changed it in `&#039;`.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

These are the menu settings of my webform:
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

This only happens when I try to translate and use `'` (apostrophe) in my translation. He will form the `'` to `&#039;`.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you give more info, how do you show description, did you use some extra module for menu or you add this on some other way?

Comment: I've added an image of my menu settings on webform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to turn off `Provide a menu link` in `Menu settings` of your webform and to add menu link to webform page in your menu, `/admin/structure/menu > list links (of your menu) > Add link` instead.

If this doesn't work you can override themable output in your theme template.php file or in a custom module. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019285/drupal-character-entity-in-menu-link-title).

Comment: This happens when I translate the original string ..

Comment: So the original is ok?

Comment: Yes the original string is ok, when I translate menu link, I get to translate title and description. Title works fine but description shows the special html chars

Comment: Updated again, it happens only with '.